# Adding fade to jquery background position animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've just implemented a background animate on some social media icons where the image goes from grey to color on `:hover`.

I wanted to know if there's a better way to write the following but also implement a fade, so as the background animates, it's also fading in on hover.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('#facebook')
        .css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} )
        .mouseover(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-63px 0px)"}, {duration:150})
        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, {duration:150})
        })
    $('#twitter')
        .css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} )
        .mouseover(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-63px 0)"}, {duration:150})
        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, {duration:150})
        })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I wanted to know if there's firstly a better way to write the following*

Well, not much to be improved but you can simplify things a little bit using `hover()`

```
$('#facebook')
.css('background-position', '0 0')
.hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'background-position' : '(-63px 0px)'
    }, 150);
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'background-position' : '(0 0)'
    }, 150);
});
```

> *implement a fade so as the background animates it's also fading in on hover*

Your best bet is to implement it with two separate images instead of a sprite. You absolute position each image on top of each other, animate their `top` for the moving effect, and then `fadeIn()|fadeOut()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `mouseover` and `mouseout` separately, you can use `hover()` which takes care of this for you. Also, as both elements have the same code being executed you could employ DRY principles and group their selectors to use one block of code. Try this:

```
$("#facebook, #twitter").css("backgroundPosition", "0 0")
    .hover(function() {
        // mouseenter
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-63px 0px)"}, {duration:150})
    },
    function() {
        // mouseleave
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, {duration:150})
    });
```

With regards to the fading in of the image, you would need to have a separate hidden `img` element above the element which fades in as you cannot put animation on the CSS background property.

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks, much cleaner. Is there a way to as well a the animate, get a fade + the animate on hover? Or would i need a seprate block of code for this?

Comment: This was a massive help, but for what i need i'm using the above suggestion of two images instead of a sprite, absolute positioning. But as ever I'm very grateful for the help. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can do this CSS and JQuery:

**CSS**

```
#facebook{
    background:url('/path/to/fb/icon/icon.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}

#twitter{
    background:url('/path/to/twitter/icon/icon.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Then in your JQuery code you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#facebook, #twitter').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'backgroundPosition':'-63px 0'}, 150);
    }, function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'backgroundPosition':'0 0'}, 150);
    });
});
```